# Fragment and Toggle Button

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am very new to Android. I am trying to add a simple toggle button to a class which extends Fragment class.

I tried everything but I could not get it working. I managed to add a normal button but that is not useful for me.

All I want is add a toggle button.

Please help me.

Thanks all

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#cccccc" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:text="Light Tab"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/fragment_button"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="61dp"
        android:text="@string/btn_fragment" />

</RelativeLayout>




package com.baris.smartgame;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Light extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.light, container, false);

        ((Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_button))
                .setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Activity activity = getActivity();

                        if (activity != null) {
                            Toast.makeText(activity,
                                    R.string.toast_you_just_clicked_a_fragment,
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                });

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use This as an Example :

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/txtDayTypes"
        android:layout_below="@+id/main_header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
   <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/tglDay1"
            android:layout_width="160dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:text="Saturday" 
            android:textOn="Saturday"
            android:textOff="Saturday"
            android:checked="true"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

and you can Access it by :

```
if(currentButton != R.id.tglDay1)  ((ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.tglDay1)).setChecked(false);
```